# crash in iOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c

There is a crash in iOS 13 in my app and I am wondering if anyone else experienced this.

So I have an nsordered set and I am trying to loop though it. I make a copy of it but it seems that when that set is empty I get this crash report: **[__NSArrayM getObjects:range:]: range {0, 1} extends beyond bounds for empty array**

Here is the code.

`(NSOrderedSet<ClassA *> *)set {
    return [self.mutableSet copy];
}`

//calling the method above to get the copy of the set

```
for (ClassA *obj in [classManager manager].set)
```

this is the stack trace:

CoreFoundation
-[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:].cold.1

CoreFoundation
-[__NSArrayM getObjects:range:]

CoreFoundation
-[NSOrderedSet countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]

Comment: Don't copy an empty array, seems pretty clear right?

Comment: That would solve this case, but I am wondering if there is something bigger happening here. I only saw crashes with empty sets, but it could happen even if it's not empty. We should be able to copy and iterate over empty sets.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is somewhere else. I just ran the following code:

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *s1 = [NSMutableOrderedSet new];
NSOrderedSet *s2 = [s1 copy];

NSOrderedSet *t1 = [NSOrderedSet new];
NSMutableOrderedSet *t2 = [t1 mutableCopy];
NSOrderedSet *t3 = [t2 copy];
NSLog(@"\n%@ %@ %@ %@ %@\n", s1, s2, t1, t2, t3);
```

This outputs:

```
{(
)} {(
)} {(
)} {(
)} {(
)}
```

I suggest that you print `self.mutableSet` - its probably not what you expect. Also your `for` line is completely out of context so no idea what's going on there. My results:

```
NSLog(@"%@ %@", NSStringFromClass([s1 class]), NSStringFromClass([t1 class]));
// __NSOrderedSetM __NSOrderedSetI
```

Comment: I am trying to loop that set, so that's what that for is for. that's where crash happens

Comment: @mertin I can add a for loop to the above, it still won't crash. Perhaps you have an object in the array that for some reason isn't retained and it causes a crash when a retain is sent to it. Please, try as I suggested to log the class name of what you think is the set, and perhaps ask it its count. Either the object isn't what you think it is (an ordered set), or whatever it contains isn't a retained NSObject subclass. I had an almost impossible to solve problem because I incorrectly added a CGColor to a collection that assumed it was a UIColor.